# AS3: Call gotoAndStop() on MainTimeline, from document class

Tags: actionscript-3

I feel like a total goose for having to ask this, it is the final piece of my project and it should be incredibly easy to solve :/ However, having visited many similar questions on here, I can report that no verified answers have solved my issues.

Basically, I want to gotoAndStop(3) on the Main Timeline from within my document class. However, I can't seem to do this.. I have tried both the following, and neither works (both throw different errors)..

```
var stageRef:Stage;
stageRef = stage;
stageRef.gotoAndStop(3)
```

Error:

```
Line 148    1061: Call to a possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:Stage.
```

The second method:

```
var MainTimeline:MovieClip = this.parent as MovieClip;
MainTimeline.gotoAndStop(3);
```

Error:

```
Line 148    1042: The this keyword can not be used in static methods. It can only be used in instance methods, function closures, and global code.
```

Both the solutions were marked as working / correct by other users, but I can't seem to get them to work.. I feel so silly. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(3);
```

Comment: cheer for the help mate :] once again, however, i am getting: Line 148 1120: Access of undefined property root

Comment: There something not quite right with your files/code then as that works fine on the test I just created.

Comment: I read up on external & document classes (as I am still relatively new to using Flash the OOP way, and I am learning slowly), and I read that apparently, the root property is null unless the document class is on the display list -- would this explain why 'root' is an undefined property for me? (i have no reason to add my document class to the display list)

Comment: i guess from here, my question is, why can i not access the root property of my document class, because all my searching has not yielded a real answer :[

Comment: No I don't think that is your problem. It's quite difficult to pinpoint the problem without seeing the code/files.

Comment: here is my document class - http://pastebin.com/LuzAg7Wg (up for the next hour). many parts are messy / unpolished, please try to ignore anything you don't think is impacting upon this error, haha :)

Comment: Try this and see what happens. Within your Control constructor function, comment everything out so you only have MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(3);

Comment: that works perfectly. unsure where to move from here, however. (ps: it also works without commenting everything out)

Comment: okay, i solved the issue now that i swapped around the definitions of some functions (in terms of public and static etc.) -- it turns out that static functions can't address root? or that seems to be a trend i just experienced. regardless, this has taught me i need to hit the books and learn how classes work a little better. thanks very much for the help :)