# .as file goToAndStop to .fla file frame

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-cs6

How can i link back from .as file function below to the 3rd frame of the .fla file stage?

```
function onComplete(e: TimerEvent):void 
{
gotoAndStop(3);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3: Call gotoAndStop() on MainTimeline, from document class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496929/as3-call-gotoandstop-on-maintimeline-from-document-class)

Comment: I would think about revising the overall programming structure of your application, keep everything simple and on one timeline one keyframe, or even better, through the use of OOP. I would also look into dispatching and creating custom listeners as well.